# Quais são as diferenças de Stored Procedures e Functions dentro do Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Esta é uma pergunta de certa forma acadêmica, porém me surgiu a dúvida.
Quais são as diferenças entre uma e outra?

O que devo considerar para escolher cada caso em determinados cenários?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stored Procedure são objetos que são compilados previamente pelo SQL e sempre que forem chamadas serão executadas à partir de seu código “pré-compilado”. Mas a Function função é compilada e executada toda vez que ela é chamada. Vamos ver algumas diferenças entre estas duas formas de tratar dados dentro do nosso banco de dados.

**A diferença básica**

- Function deve retornar um valor, mas em stored o retorno é opcional.
- As functions podem ter apenas parâmetros de entrada. As storeds podem
  ter parâmetros de entrada / saída.
- Functions podem ser chamadas de dentro de storeds, já as storeds não
  podem ser chamados a partir de functions.

**Diferenças avançadas**

- Procedures não podem ser utilizadas em uma instrução SELECT enquanto
  que a function pode ser incorporado em uma instrução SELECT.
- Procedures não podem ser chamadas e/ou utilizadas nas instruções de
  SQL em qualquer lugar do WHERE/HAVING/SELECT, enquanto que a function
  pode ser.
- A característica mais importante de storeds procedures em relação a functions é a de retenção e reutilização do plano de execução, enquanto no caso da função que irá ser compilada cada vez que for executada.
- Functions que retornam tabelas podem ser tratadas como um outro
  conjunto dados. Isto quer dizer que podemos utilizá-las em
  associações (JOINS) com outras tabelas.
- Exceções podem ser tratadas por bloco try-catch em um storeds
  enquanto bloco try-catch não pode ser usado em uma function.
- Podemos utilizar Transaction Management em um stored, e não em uma
  function.

Espero ter ajudado.

Fonte: [Código Simples](http://codigosimples.net/2016/02/24/principais-diferencas-entre-stored-procedures-e-functions/)